# Scala : Extract values to bypass JVM method length

Tags: scala, refactoring

I have a method which length exceeds the 64k JVM limit. It looks like there is no trivial way to bypass the problem, therefore I might have to refactor my code. I am a Scala noob and I would need some advice on this :

```
def apply = {
...
val container = Map(...<Some Really Long Input>...)
val anotherContainer = Map(...<Some Really Long Input>...)
...
}
```

How can I extract the content of the above variables, knowing that their content depends on some data within the *apply* method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could abuse closures to get some of the code out of the method:

```
val container = (() => Map(...<Some Really Long Input>...))()
```

I really hope that this is automatically generated code. If it isn't, there are many better ways to refactor your code and make it more readable and maintainable. One of them would be to put the code that creates the map into its own method and pass the data inside the `apply` method as parameters.

Comment: Yes, this is autogenerated code indeed. It is related to Gatling, a load benchmarker that puts a shitload of HTTP traffic into the above method. I am going to try the closure way right now.